# Get Visit Counts from Different Locations

Tags: mysql, subquery

`visit` mysql table:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------+
| visitId | visitSiteId | homeSiteId | userId |       time          |
+---------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------+
|   1     |      1      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-01 11:50:12 |
|   2     |      1      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-03 12:50:12 |
|   3     |      2      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-04 13:50:12 |
|   4     |      2      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-07 11:00:00 |
|   5     |      2      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-09 12:32:12 |
|   6     |      2      |     1      |  1001  | 2013-09-13 15:48:12 |
|   7     |      2      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-01 11:00:12 |
|   8     |      2      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-02 12:50:12 |
|   9     |      2      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-05 13:50:12 |
|   10    |      1      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-06 11:50:12 |
|   11    |      1      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-07 12:50:12 |
|   12    |      2      |     2      |  1002  | 2013-09-15 13:50:12 |
+---------+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Records visit datetime, the Site Visited and the Users Home Site

I want to find how to Output 3 Reports From above data.

1. Return any users who have a Non Home Site Visit Count >= HomeSite Visit Count; any Date
2. Return any users who have a Non Home Site Visit Count >= a Minimum entered Integer e.g. Non Home Count >= 10
3. Both 1 and 2 with Date Range i.e. Time >= '2013-09-01 11:50:12' AND Time <= '2013-09-13 15:48:12'

I am very new to MySQL and struggle with subquery syntax so would appreciate any assistance:
The Queries Below will return the counts of Home Visits and Non Home Visits but I cannot get my head around Subquery for combined result

```
SELECT COUNT(v.user_id), v.user_id FROM visit v WHERE v.Site <> v.HomeSite GROUP BY v.user_id;
SELECT COUNT(v.user_id), v.user_id FROM visit v WHERE v.Site = v.HomeSite GROUP BY v.user_id;
SELECT COUNT(v.user_id), v.user_id FROM visit v WHERE v.Site <> v.HomeSite AND v.Time >= '2013-09-01 11:50:12' AND v.Time <= '2013-09-13 15:48:12' GROUP BY v.user_id;
SELECT COUNT(v.user_id), v.user_id FROM visit v WHERE v.Site = v.HomeSite AND v.Time >= '2013-09-01 11:50:12' AND v.Time <= '2013-09-13 15:48:12' GROUP BY v.user_id;
```

Here is the MySQL Create Table and INSERT Data to assist with testing:

```
 CREATE TABLE `dbName`.`visit`(`visitId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `visitSiteId` INT(11), `homeSiteId` INT(11), `userId` INT(11), `time` DATETIME, PRIMARY KEY (`visitId`));

INSERT INTO `dbName`.`visit`(`visitSiteId`,`homeSiteId`,`userId`,`time`) VALUES
  (1,1,1001,'2013-09-01 11:50:12'),
  (1,1,1001,'2013-09-03 12:50:12'),
  (2,1,1001,'2013-09-04 13:50:12'),
  (2,1,1001,'2013-09-07 11:00:00'),
  (2,1,1001,'2013-09-09 12:32:12'),
  (2,1,1001,'2013-09-13 15:48:12'),
  (2,1,1002,'2013-09-01 11:00:12'),
  (2,1,1002,'2013-09-02 12:50:12'),
  (2,1,1002,'2013-09-05 13:50:12'),
  (1,1,1002,'2013-09-06 11:50:12'),
  (1,1,1002,'2013-09-07 12:50:12'),
  (2,1,1002,'2013-09-15 13:50:12');
```

Comment: Sorry, the layout did not come out as in text editor. The queries at bottom of question will build and insert the table data.

Comment: And what is the desired output for each required report based on provided sample data or combined report (BTW it's not clear from your question)?

Answer (score 0):

Not Tried and tested..

```
SELECT Count(visitId) AS Visits, userId 
    FROM homeSiteId 
    GROUP BY visitId HAVING Count(visitId) > 2999
```

Comment: Not what I am after. Specifically I need non home visit Counts compared to home visit counts.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. You have to use CASE statement to count the home site and non home site visits separately.

Query 1

```
select userid
  from (
  select userid,
         count(case when visitsiteid = homesiteid then 1 end) homesitecount,   --count only those records where home site = visited site
         count(case when visitsiteid != homesiteid then 1 end) nonhomesitecount  --count only those records where home site != visited site
    from visit
   group by userid) as groupedvisit             --use this as inline view and filter out the users. 
 where nonhomesitecount >= homesitecount;
```

Query 2

```
select userid,
       count(case when visitsiteid != homesiteid then 1 end) nonhomesitecount
  from visit
 group by userid
having count(case when visitsiteid != homesiteid then 1 end) > 3;
```

Next queries are similar to Query1 and 2. You'll have to add an extra where clause to restrict the date.

```
where time >= lower_limit and time <= upper_limit
```

Demo at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe8c/6)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** If understand correctly what you want you can do it like this

> *1. Return any users who have a Non Home Site Visit Count >= HomeSite Visit Count; any Date*

```sql
SELECT userid, 
       SUM(visitsiteid <> homesiteid) visitsnonhome,
       SUM(visitsiteid = homesiteid) visitshome
  FROM visit
 GROUP BY userid
HAVING visitsnonhome >= visitshome;
```

> *2. Return any users who have a Non Home Site Visit Count >= a Minimum entered Integer*

```sql
SELECT userid, 
       SUM(visitsiteid <> homesiteid) visitsnonhome,
       SUM(visitsiteid = homesiteid) visitshome
  FROM visit
 GROUP BY userid
HAVING visitsnonhome >= 3;
```

> *3. Both 1 and 2 with Date Range...*

Just add a `WHERE` clause to above-mentioned queries

```
SELECT userid, 
       SUM(visitsiteid <> homesiteid) visitsnonhome,
       SUM(visitsiteid = homesiteid) visitshome
  FROM visit
 WHERE time >= '2013-09-01 11:50:12' 
   AND time <= '2013-09-13 15:48:12'
 GROUP BY userid
HAVING visitsnonhome >= visitshome;

SELECT userid, 
       SUM(visitsiteid <> homesiteid) visitsnonhome,
       SUM(visitsiteid = homesiteid) visitshome
  FROM visit
 WHERE time >= '2013-09-01 11:50:12' 
   AND time <= '2013-09-13 15:48:12'
 GROUP BY userid
HAVING visitsnonhome >= 3;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f23e6/6)** demo

Comment: Thanks, that is heading in the right direction, only thing missing is I want to return the Counts for both home and None home site.

Comment: e.g Output would look like

Comment: userId,VisitsNonHome, VisitsHome
1001, 4, 2
1002, 4, 2

Comment: @user2214008 See updated answer and sqlfiddle example. BTW your question doesn't clear on desired output. It says *...Return any **users** who have...* no mention of counts.

Comment: I have checked the SQLFiddle demo and it is perfect. Thank you.    Yes you are correct, my apologies, to busy trying to get the formatting right for the question and neglected to ask it the correct way. Struggling to even get a new line in the comment section, as you can tell by the disastrous 3 comments above.